# Detect mouse action on click

Tags: c++, function, mouse

How can I detect if a click on a `(x,y)` coordinates point will create any action?
For example is there any bool function (in c++) or something like that which can tell me if a double-click on `(200,200)` coordinates point will create any action before actually making the click?

Comment: You have not shown what you have tried or researched so far. And you don't even say which system. Mouse clicks and GUIs are not part of standard C++. It is your responsibility as a developer to choose a library or framework for your compiler and operating system, weighing pros and cons of all possible choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReadConsoleInput` for mouse event.

You can check out microsoft domentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx

Sample code again:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
    cout<<"click anywhere in console window to write - hello world -\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    "Press Ctrl+C to Exit"; 

        HANDLE hout= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
        INPUT_RECORD InputRecord; 
        DWORD Events; 
        COORD coord;
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
        cci.dwSize = 25;
        cci.bVisible = FALSE;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(hout, &cci); 
        SetConsoleMode(hin, ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT); 


    while(1)
    { 

        ReadConsoleInput(hin, &InputRecord, 1, &Events); 

        if(InputRecord.EventType == MOUSE_EVENT) 
        {
            if(InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED) 
            { 
                coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X; 
                coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y; 
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hout,coord);
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hout,rand() %7+9);

                cout<<"Hello world" ; 

            } 
        }
        FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hin);
    }
    return 0;

}
```